# How to create a new database .mdb with Python

Tags: python, database, ms-access, pyodbc

Hello I've been searching around and couldn't find anything up to date in this topic.

I would like to create a new .mdb file using pythons library pyodbc.

I've tried so many different ways and can never succeed.
The main problem for me is to connect to a database that yet does not exist.

```
import pyodbc
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
PWD = ''
con=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,'./'+new_path+'.mdb',PWD))
```

I've tried inserting a

```
f=open(new_path+'.mdb','a')
f.close()
```

in order to create a mdb file before trying to connect but could not succeed as well, it says that the file is corrupted.

Comment: Use the [msaccessdb](https://github.com/gordthompson/msaccessdb) module.

Comment: Well I'm getting blocked to install other libraries, but I'll try it, thanks

Comment: If it's a permissions issue then try `pip install --user msaccessdb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [msaccessdb](https://github.com/gordthompson/msaccessdb) module for that. After you

```
pip install msaccessdb
```

or

```
pip install --user msaccessdb
```

you can simply do

```py
import msaccessdb
msaccessdb.create(r'C:\path\to\new.mdb')
```